# Get data to variable on sqljocky, using dart

Tags: dart

I want to get data from mysql with the Dart library "sqljocky" to a variable.
Then I will sent that variable to client through Socket

```
  cnx.connect(user:user, password:password, port:port, db:db, host:host).chain((nothing) {
    log.debug("got connection");
    return cnx.useDatabase(db);
  }).chain((dummy) {
    return cnx.query("select * from tablename");
  });
```

anyway to do that,
thanks

Comment: Have you established connection to your MySQL DB from Dart ?

Comment: yes, but i want to get value after query

Comment: and you have a websocket connection already established with the client ?

Comment: yes, i using db<--sqljocky-->server<--socket-->client. I don't know how to get value after cnx.query :((

Comment: @Lars Tackmann. Do you have any idea?

Comment: what happens if you in the cnx.query stores the result in a var and then log it before you return it ?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of Dart and the API of sqljocky has changed slightly since the question was posted. This is how you would now get results from a query in sqljocky.

```
var pool = new ConnectionPool(user:user, password:password, port:port, db:db, host:host);
pool.query('select * from tablename').then((result) {
  for (var row in result) {
    print("A row:");
    for (var col in row) {
      print(col);
    }
  }
});
```